# Invalid hook call in work with local Storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, local-storage

I have a 3 files:

- Main component,
- File with states that are stored in local storage
- A file with a reset function for resetting these same states to default
  values.

I import the file with the states and reset file in the main component and everything is ok. But when I try use reset function for set localState value to default, i got error “Error: Invalid hook call. Interceptors can only be called inside the body of a functional component. "

I read the documentation on react, but I did not understand the error

First file code:

```
import React from "react";
import { LocalStorage } from "./localState";
import { resetLocalStorage } from "./resetLocalState";

function App() {
  const localState = LocalStorage(); // local storage keys
  const resetState = () => resetLocalStorage(); // reset local storate states

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => resetState()}>Refresh State to default</button>
      <br />
      <button
        onClick={() => localState.setLocalStorageState("State was changed")}
      >
        Change State
      </button>
      <p>{localState.localStorageState}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Second file code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useLocalStorageList = (key, defaultValue) => {
  const stored = localStorage.getItem(key);
  const initial = stored ? JSON.parse(stored) : defaultValue;
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initial);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [key, value]);

  return [value, setValue];
};

//local storage keys
export const LocalStorage = () => {
  const [localStorageState, setLocalStorageState] = useLocalStorageList(
    "State",
    "Default Value"
  );

  return { localStorageState, setLocalStorageState };
};
```

Third file code

```
import { LocalStorage } from "./localState";

export const resetLocalStorage = () => {
  const localState = LocalStorage(); //local storage keys
  localState.setLocalStorageState("Default Value");
};
```

[Link to SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-galileo-r2t37?file=/src/resetLocalState.jsx:0-200)

Comment: Convert LocalStorage into custom hooks too

Comment: Custom hooks should start with "use". https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Comment: The reset function is not a valid hook. Hooks must be in the body of a function component, Yours is part of a function inside the component. That's not allowed

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? This looks way too complex in my eyes for your use case

Comment: @messerbill, thats code is for example, my real code is more massive and therefore I want to split my code into small parts

Answer (score 1):

I didnt see anything to reset all states in your `resetLocalStorage()`. I assume you will keep track of all the 'local storage keys' and define reset-functions for each. [This example](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-almeida-rr78l?file=/src/localState.jsx:583-601) modifies your hook to return a third function to reset the state so another reset-function doesn't have top be defined.

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-sound-0yxvl?file=/src/App.js

I made few changes in your code to achieve the use case you were trying to achieve. (Let me know my implementation is suffices your use case)

The resetLocalStorage is not starting with `use` That's why you were getting the previous error.
After renaming that function to `useResetLocalStorage`, still it will not work since -

you were calling the custom hook onClick of button. This breaks one react hook rule which is `react hooks must not be called conditionally`  https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

Comment: Can you explain what is the point of keeping `resetLocalState.jsx` (you also change its name to `useResetLocalStorage`) whilst you are directly using `useLocalStorage` for both set and reset buttons?

Comment: ```resetLocalState.jsx``` can be deleted. Now it is not required. (I started with rename as first step and as I mentioned in my answer it didn't worked)

Comment: my code here and on sandBox is for example, my real code is more massive and therefore I want to split my code into small parts. Your solution will work, but it creates a lot of unnecessary code, because I have many states and if you apply your solution, then for each state there will be its own setState, but I want all states (and there are about 70 of them) to be reset to default one by one click